# rabbitmq specific routing key not accepted

Tags: rabbitmq

I am facing an issue in rabbitmq when I try to create a binding between exchange (type: topic) and queue.

Whenever I try to create the binding using a particular key it doesn't work but when I use some different keys, it works

e.g the key "asd.fywm.gjfritecrwmw.qoermah" works but "asd.fywm.gjfritecrwmw.qoermag" wont work

Error message while creating the bind:

```
 =ERROR REPORT==== 19-Sep-2017::09:39:45 ===
Channel error on connection <0.29697.2398> (<rabbit@Servername.3.29697.2398>, vhost: 'MY-VHOST', user: 'user'), channel 1:
operation queue.bind caused a channel exception not_found: "no binding asd.fywm.gjfritecrwmw.qoermag between exchange 'MY_EXCHANGE' in vhost 'MY-VHOST' and queue 'my_q' in vhost 'MY-VHOST'"
```

Is there any possibility that its causing due to routing key value somehow still being present somewhere in Mnesia db of rabbitmq?

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As per my communication in below forum, it looks like upgrade is the only option.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/CeaOic-oPYs